# I cannot get access to all desired elements using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, selectors-api, nodelist

So I have these three lists which I want to hide.

```
 <ul id="wordsb" class="wordslist" class="list1">
        <li class="list-group-item">list1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">dancing</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">elephant</li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="wordsb1" class="wordslist" class="list2">
        <li class="list-group-item">list2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">man</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">dog</li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="wordsb2" class="wordslist" class="list3">
        <li class="list-group-item">list3</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">plane</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">truck</li>
      </ul>
```

I am using the queryselectorall in order to access the ids loop through them, applying a style to each of them:

```
 var gameb = document.querySelectorAll("#wordsb", "#wordsb1", "#wordsb2");
for (var i = 0; i < gameb.length; i++) {
  gameb[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Unfortunately, only the first list (wordsb) is hidden as desired, and the remaining two elements do not seem to be impacted. When I console.log(gameb) I found that the node list only includes wordsb, and not the other two elements. `enter code here`

Comment: Haha, I just realized I had multiple  " ", thus making multiple parameters. Stupid Mistake. Thanks for the quick reply tho anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) only takes one parameter:

```js
var gameb = document.querySelectorAll("#wordsb, #wordsb1, #wordsb2");
for (var i = 0; i < gameb.length; i++) {
  gameb[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<ul id="wordsb" class="wordslist" class="list1">
  <li class="list-group-item">list1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">dancing</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">elephant</li>
</ul>
<ul id="wordsb1" class="wordslist" class="list2">
  <li class="list-group-item">list2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">man</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">dog</li>
</ul>
<ul id="wordsb2" class="wordslist" class="list3">
  <li class="list-group-item">list3</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">plane</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">truck</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was just a silly mistake, document.queryselectorall only takes one parameter, and I accidentally put quotation marks around each of my elements. Thereby, making multiple parameters. Thus the node list didnt reflect all three of my elements.